# Clustering with vertx.io

Tags: vert.x, vertx3

As I read, there are two types of clustering: horizontal and vertical.

I am trying vertical clustering with vertx.io.

I have two vertx applications running on two different machines.
One application creates a TCP server while other application creates a HTTP server. Now I want to publish some messages on event bus that should be listen by vertical running TCP server.

I follow the these [steps](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/) from vertx. I am not able to listen to messages published by the HTTP server on even bus.

Is vertical scaling supported by Vertx?

Answer (score 0):

Run the applications with **-cluster** option like on first machine,

```
java -jar create-http-server-fat.jar -cluster
```

and on the other,

```
java -jar create-tcp-server-fat.jar -cluster
```

Then, your eventbuses will be able to communicate.
*Ensure that both the machines are connected via the same network.*

**-cluster : This option determines whether the Vert.x instance will attempt to form a cluster with other Vert.x instances on the network. Clustering Vert.x instances allows Vert.x to form a distributed event bus with other nodes. Default is false (not clustered).**

Important : You need to have vertx-hazelcast-3.0.0 jar added to your classpath.